# Do we have to create new popup every time there is an update on google crome?

Tags: javascript

Do we have to create new popup if google crome updated or we can continue with the older one.

Comment: huh? what u talkin bout willis

Comment: i mean yes. you should create a new pop up every 30 seconds if you wan tto keep your browser clean/

Comment: Are you asking if you have to update chrome? The browser? Like to new versions? What popup? Who is we? You'll have to give more details. Anything.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  You can take the [tour] first and learn [ask] a good question.  That makes it easier for us to help you.

Comment: I mean i use add popups but it doesn't work whenever there is update on crome and my developer always ask to go for new popup even i don't know whither it stop working or not, may be he is making me fool....

Comment: he always charge me 10k for every popup to create.

Comment: Ssinghal. I will create pop ups for you for only 9k. Call me.

Comment: bro don't you think its too high if i have to get it ready every time whenever there is an update in crome, secondly i am asking it necessary, cant be older popup will work or can't it work by making small changes. so i have these questions and looking for genuine answer.

Answer (score 0):

No one is sure what you're asking, but I'm going to take a stab at it. I believe you're asking if you have to use a new popup every time an advertisement is changed? If that is the case, the answer is no, you don't always have to have a new popup. HOWEVER, if the window was closed by the user, a new popup will have to be created. The following code will bring a named window to the front:

```
function GetAdWindow() {
    // Change the window.open parameters to your liking
    var AdWindow = window.open("", "AdWindow", "toolbar=no,location=no,status=no,menubar=no,scrollbars=yes,resizable=no,width=500,height=500");
    return AdWindow;
}
```

After that, you have to determine if the page is blank, or already has an advertisement on it.

```
function UpdateAd(){
    var AdWindow = GetAdWindow();

    // If the AdWindow wasn't populated (meaning it was closed)
    if (AdWindow.location.href === "about:blank") {
        AdWindow.location = /*ADVERTISEMENT URL*/
    } else {
    // DO WHATEVER YOU WANT IF THE WINDOW HAD CONTENT
    }
}
```

If you asking if your popup will go away if Chrome has an update, the answer is yes. Chrome as a whole will shot down and close all of the windows, then start back up clean.